# Batch script for editing a text file

Tags: text, batch-file, editor

We have a txt file that is getting populated by a database dump, but there are `CR` and `LF` breaks, that we don't want. Basically, I am trying to edit `C:\app.txt`, remove all `CR`s and `LF`s, and then add `!@#` in front of `"_TEXT_"`, and add a `CR` in front of `"!@#_TEXT_"`. This way, I only have `CR` in the places I want them, not all over the place.

I have tried using change.exe by Bruce Gunthrie, which worked well in a 32 bit environment, but doesn't work on a 64bit PC.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

I saw some similar posts here, but have trouble reading the codes because they are too complex, so I didn't know how to adapt them for our environment.

Thanks

Luke

eg.

```
_TEXT_ data data1
data2 data3 data4
_TEXT_ data data1
data2 data3 data4
```

Should read:

```
_TEXT_ data data1 data2 data3 data4
_TEXT_ data data1 data2 data3 data4
```

Comment: Manipulting files at the byte level (especially with custom line breaks) is *hard* in batch files ...

Answer (score 1):

Is PowerShell an option? (I would guess so, a 64-bit computer with a current Windows version *has* PowerShell installed.)

```
$(
  $line = ''
  switch -wildcard -File C:\app.txt {
    '_TEXT_*' {
      if ($line) { $line }
      $line = "!@#$_"
    }
    default {
      $line += ' ' + $_
    }
  }
  if ($line) { $line }
) -join "`r"
```

This will join the lines with CR, as you wished. Pipe the result to `Set-Content` to write it to a file.

Comment: Thanks for the script, but I have no idea on how to pipe to text.  I've tried the Set-Content, but it keeps asking for `Content:0` or something. Are you able to help me again?

Comment: <br/> I have piped the file to a txt document by simply using `app.ps1 > C:\app1.txt`, however, it places it all on one line. Thanks for your help

Comment: Hi Joey, Got it all working now except the `set-content`, are you able to assist with that.  Thanks for this, I had been working on this for days.

Comment: Instead of `> foo.txt` you can use `| Set-Content foo.txt` which also allows you to set an encoding with `-Encoding UTF8` for example.

Comment: Hi Joey,  Thanks this is now working 100%.  Thank you for all your assistance.